# How to make conditional formatting of different type of dynamic array using formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have an array (dynamically change) in the spreadsheet cell A1:A

0.0109
6.5476

-6.11
-21.7

-28.18
0.2694
-90.66

-1.45
0.4047
-49.88
0.1335
0.6004
0.0954

The above values are text formatted instead of numeric. I want to conditionally format in colours as if value(array)>0 then show green. I want to do this using formula within conditional formatting tab. I have prepared an [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1EdanAZl3OETwv7xpxbuojEHKcTxLenYVQ0ToOuRo8SI/edit#gid=0) to format this. In array A1:A, i have used simple conditional formatting if A1:A greater than 0 then green, but it is not working.

Comment: Also for less than zero shown as yellow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*since the incoming numbers in Column_A are text-formatted(for reasons), use the following `custom formula` instead:*

```js
=value(A1)>0
```

Comment: if i need value(A1)<0.5 as yellow and IGNORE BLANK/EMPTY CELLS?

Comment: `=len(A1)*(value(A1)<0.5)`